# Access to Mono.Cecil.dll is denied when installing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, nuget

I am trying to install the nuget package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps however when I attempt to install it i get the error "Access to the path 'Mono.Cecil.dll' is denied".  I cannot find any reason why access would be denied and Mono.Cecil.dll does not appear to be read only. Any insight into this problem would be great.

Comment: Receiving the same error trying to update base Xamarin.Forms packages to 27.0.2

Comment: Were you able to figure out the problem?

Comment: Nope! One of the members on my team was able to get the map working and he didn't run into these issues so I am unfortunately unable to tell you exactly what the problem was.